# Django ajax jQuery autocomplete only works on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I've added a working search field to a navigation bar that use jQuery autocomplete.  The problem is it only works on the main page.  On the other pages it tries to add the source url to the end of the page url.

For instance, on the home page it points to `ajax_call/search`, but on a company page (it's app that gathers internal data on companies) it points to `company/847/ajax_call/search` and obviously fails.

What do I need to do so the jQuery autocomplete functionality works across the entire site (without rewriting it in every template)?

**Template**

```
$(function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        minLength:2,
        source: "ajax_call/search/",
        select: function(event, ui){
            window.location.href = ui.item.href;
        }
    });
});
```

**URL**

```
url(r'^ajax_call/search/$', views.ajax_company_search, name='search-field'),
```

**View**

```
def ajax_company_search(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        query = request.GET.get('term', '')
        company_names = Company.objects.filter(company_name__icontains=query).values('company_name', 'pk')

        results = []
        for name in company_names:
            name_json = dict()
            name_json['label'] = name['company_name']
            name_json['value'] = name['company_name']
            name_json['href'] = "company/" + str(name['pk']) + "/"

            results.append(name_json)

        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified a [relative URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs) in your JavaScript function. That's why it changes when you visit another page (with a different URL). In this case you want to use an absolute URL, like this: `/ajax_call/search/`.

Also, it is best practice to not hard-code your URLs in templates but to use [reverse resolution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls):

```
$(function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        minLength:2,
        source: {% url 'search-field' %},
        select: function(event, ui){
            window.location.href = ui.item.href;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, reverse resolution, why didn't I think of that?!!  I had tried using an absolute path, but looking back I didn't include my app name ("main") which is why it failed.  Anyways, thanks for the help!